# Android: Implement a number slider

Tags: java, android, slider

I've been searching the net for two days now, but I couldn't find anything on this topic. When you set an alarm clock on your Android phone, you can choose the time with two number slides (not sure if they're called like this).

Is there a way to use them in my own app?

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) could be what you are looking for.

An example of its use [is here](http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5).